# why does not toString method work in my priorityqueue code?

Tags: java

this is my work class which adds works with their priority and ı used comparable interface to obtain priority among works.

```
public class Work implements Comparable<Work>{
    private String work;
    private int pri;
    
    //this is constuctor
    public Work(String work, int pri){
        this.work = work;
        this.pri = pri;
    } 

    //this is implementation of compareTo method
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Work o) {
        if (this.pri < o.pri)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  this.work;
    }   
}
```

and this is the part which is in regard to the priority queue

```
        int option = 0;
        String work;
        int urgency;
        PriorityQueue<Work> works = new PriorityQueue<Work>();
        do {
            System.out.println("enter what you want\n1.add work\n2.next\n3.quit ");
            option = scan.nextInt();
            if (option == 1) {
                System.out.println("what is work ");
                work = scan.nextLine();
                scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("how is your work urgency ");
                urgency = scan.nextInt();
                works.add(new Work(work, urgency));
            }
            if (option == 2) {
                while (!works.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println(works.poll());
                }
            }
        } while (option != 3);
```

while option 1 and 3 works well,
option 2 is not working it understand the work just blank line and output is just a blank line.
thanks in advance!!

sorry for giving not the necessary info because of StackOverflow rules(mostly code).

Comment: @JohannesKuhn i think i handled with this problem writing extra scan.nextLine :(

Comment: Not really. You read the rest of the selection. Suppose the user enters `1 foo\nbar\n1`, then you would get a work with prio = 1 and work = foo.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet didn't show us how `scan` was declared, but from the method names I'm guessing that it's a `java.util.Scanner`.  That can be difficult to use.

```
System.out.println("what is work ");
work = scan.nextLine();
System.err.println("HAVE READ >>" + work + "<< into work");   // <------
scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("how is your work urgency ");
```

A good starting point would be the line I've added there.  As soon as you read that input, print it back out, because that's what your `toString` is returning.  If your `toString` is not doing what you expect, it's a good sign that the input to "work" might not be what you're assuming it is.

You might want to move to some kind of loop there also, like

```
work = null;
while (work is null or empty or otherwise invalid) {
    System.out.print("what is work?  ");
    work = scan in the text;
    test work for empty input, like a line of only spaces, etc;
}
// do the same thing for urgency, etc
```

But that can come after checking that the `nextLine()` is doing what you think it is.

Don't forget to remove the System.err line once you're done!